# Error compiling LWJGL example with Java/NetBeans

Tags: java, compiler-errors, lwjgl

I recently looked at these tutorials on LWJGL. I'm trying to compile them in a NetBeans environment. But it gives an error:

> Cannot find symbol.
>   Location: class Texture;
>   Method: getTexture ();

I declare the method as follows:

```
public Texture getTexture () {
    return texture;
}
```

Location of method: class TModel.

```
package mod.els;

import mis.ter.pin.Model;
import text.ures.Texture;

public class TModel {
    private Model model;
    private Texture texture;

    public TModel(Model model, Texture texture) {
        this.model = model;
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    public Model getRawModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return texture;
    }
}
```

And class Texture:

```
package text.ures;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Texture {
    private int textureID;

    public Texture(int id) {
        this.textureID = id;
    }

    public int getTextureID() {
        return this.textureID;
    }
}
```

Class Model:

```
package mis.ter.pin;

public class Model {
    private int vaoID;
    private int vertexCount;

    public Model(int vaoID, int vertexCount) {
        this.vaoID = vaoID;
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
    }

    public int getVaoID() {
        return vaoID;
    }

    public int getVertexCount() {
        return vertexCount;
    }
}
```

Tutorials on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP

Comment: It's a pity. Everywhere they complain about me.

Comment: @Kareist: They shouldn't complain about you, but your input.

Comment: Added code indention. Fixed obvious typos.